# Webscraping Bing wallpapers

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I wanted to scrape all the wallpapers from the [Bing wallpaper gallery](http://www.bing.com/gallery/).  This was for personal use and to learn about webscraping.  The gallery progressively gets images using javascript as the user scrolls down the page.  Then you can download the high-resolution image with a few clicks.  I actually succeeded in scraping all the wallpapers, but I sort of "cheated" and wanted to know if there's a better way.

Here's what I did:

First, I went to the site in the browser, started capturing network traffic with developer tools, and scrolled all the way down the page as far as possible.  Then I exported the log to a .csv file.  This produced a bunch of URLs like:

> http://az619519.vo.msecnd.net/files/PolandFarm_EN-US8019728095_320x180.jpg

Luckily, the full resolution version (for almost every image) is located in the same place, except with "1920x1200" substituted at the end:

> http://az619519.vo.msecnd.net/files/PolandFarm_EN-US8019728095_1920x1200.jpg

I ran the following script to retrieve the full resolution images:

```
import csv
import os
import re
import urllib.request

target_dir = 'C:/Users/[Username]/Desktop/Bing'

def main():
    os.chdir(target_dir)
    with open('NetworkData.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        for line in csv.reader(csvfile):
            url_request = repr(line[0])
            if r'vo.msecnd.net/files' in url_request:
                pic_url = re.sub('_\d+x\d+\.jpg', '_1920x1200.jpg', url_request)
                pic_url = pic_url.strip('\'"')
                try:
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url, pic_url.split('/')[-1])
                except:
                    print("Image not found.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I thought this solution was actually okay, but I was wondering if there was a way to automate or avoid the manual step of capturing the network traffic.  I was hoping to avoid selenium if possible, because it looks kind of slow and cumbersome.  Also, if you have any advice on improving the script, that would be good.  I had some issues with string encoding, and I feel like in the end the script isn't very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only use one function from both `re` and `os`, you could just import the specific function from each rather than the whole module.

```
from os import chdir
from re import sub
```

You shouldn't use a bare `try except`. You might be ignoring all sorts of errors without noticing. Instead, use the exception that you're expecting is likely to happen. According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428918/4374739) `urlretrieve` will likely `raise` a `URLError` (which you also need to get with `import URLError from urllib2`). This way if you're having other problems you'll actually know about it.

```
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url, pic_url.split('/')[-1])
except URLError:
    print("Image not found.")
```

Also it seems silly to have that message print out without indicating which images weren't found. You may be incorrectly parsing a lot of images without realising it. Just adding `(pic_url.split('/')[-1] + " Image not found")` would make it a much more useful error message. But it would be even more helpful if you logged the full path (`pic_url`).